# Android, обработка касания

Tags: java, android

У меня есть кнопка А и кнопка В. Пользователь касается кнопки А и, не отрывая пальца от экрана, ведёт его к кнопке В. Как обработать касание обоих кнопок? OnTouchListener не работает. Он, как я понял, обрабатывает события касания/движения только в пределах одного View.

Comment: drag and drop что ли?

Comment: Нет. Пользователь касается одной кнопки, она срабатывает. Затем он, не отпуская палец, ведёт его ко второй кнопке. Срабатывает вторая кнопка. Обе остаются на своих местах.

Comment: а зачем это надо? ;)

Comment: Задал вопрос, значит надо:) Какая разница, зачем?

Comment: setOnTouchListener